# Apache2 server (behind Zyxel USG 100 NAT/Firewall) with vhost does not log real clients ip addresses

Tags: apache-2.2, firewall, logging, nat, virtualhost

**SOLVED**

To allow the Zyxel USG 100's NAT to forward untouched packets to my web server i edited the policy route of the Zyxel.

```
Zyxel -> Configuration -> Network ->Routing -> Policy Route
```

I just edit the "Address Translation" option from "outgoing-interface" to "none"

Now apache is logging true external clients ip addresses

---

**SOLVED**

Good morning mates

today i'm facing a problem to correctly log clients request onto my corporate Apache2 web server

Network scheme:

```
////////////    _                      WAN1   11.11.11.12
| INTERNET /  _/  ===> CISCO Router =======> first public ip ==> to corporate LAN
////////////                      || 
                                  || 
                                  || 
                                  || zyxel eth0 ip: 11.11.11.11
                                  || label: WAN2
                                  \/
              ZYXEL ROUTER   ___ eth0 _________________________________________________
                             |   ZYXEL                                                |
                             |   Gateway
                             |    ||                                                  |
                             |    ||                                                  |
                             |   |\/| FIREWALL (accept request from eth0/WAN2 on port |                  
                             |    ||            443/80 and forward them to LAN1)      |
                             |    ||                                                  |
                             |   |\/| NAT (forward request on 11.11.11.11:80 to       |
                             |    ||        web server on 192.168.1.10:80)            |
                             |____||__________________________________________________|
                                  *zyxel eth1 ip: 192.168.1.1, label: lan1*
                                  ||
                                  \|____________________
                                   |                    \   mysqlserver 192.168.1.20
                           ________|                    ++
  webserver 192.168.1.10  / 
                         ++
```

When someone (from Internet or my private lan) request a page to my public ip 11.11.11.11 on port 80, my webserver respond to it correctly. But when i want to check access.log of my web server i can see only my Zyxel router ip 192.168.1.1 logged.

I suppose there is a NAT problem, it seems that the Zyxel subsitutes its ip address as SRC of IP packets coming to my webserver.

What i have to do to get a properly logged web requests with public clients ip addresses?
Router is the Zyxel USG 100

this is my Apache2 log configurations (apache2.log)

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

this is my vhost log configuration

```
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/xyz.com/access.log combined
```

Thanks

Comment: Rather than putting the answer in the question it's OK to self-answer once you have an answer.

Comment: ok, thank you. Should i report here the solution?

Comment: Yes, please. New users might have to wait a bit before answering their own question, but it's better if you post the answer as...well, an answer.

Answer (score 0):

%{X-ClientSide}i may be what you want to add to your logformat to get the remote address of the client.

Comment: Thank you for your 2cents but as i expected it was a Nat/Firewall or Routing problem.